# Child height not being calculated when parent height is set in percentage

Tags: html, css, height

I have an HTML code that looks like this:

```
<div id="menu_bg">
    <div class="menu_possitioner">
        <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS which looks like this:

```
#menu_bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 10;
    display: table;
}
.menu_bg .menu_possitioner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
. menu_bg.menu_possitioner .menu-main-menu-container {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    max-width: 440px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 250px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
. menu_bg.menu_possitioner .menu-main-menu-container ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

This is basically a lightbox-like menu and the idea is that the `<ul>` should not be higher that 100%-250px and allow the user to scroll if the items in the list require more space.

This works good in Chrome, but on Firefox it doesn’t seem to work unless I set the .menu_possitioner to a specific height in px instead of a percentage. The thing is I really need this to be a percentage (100%) because it needs to cover the whole screen no matter the size of it.

Comment: `. menu_bg.menu_possitioner .menu-main-menu-container` only here, or in your actual code?

Comment: @Michael_B you can see the real thing here http://mirlostudio.com/mission. If you make your browser small-ish and navigate to the menu-featured hicks you'll see what happens (not on Chrome which works well)

Comment: Scroll works fine for me in FF. It's not styled, like in Chrome, but it works. Also, consider `overflow-y: auto` instead of `scroll`, so track disappears when not necessary.

Comment: @Michael_B the scroll works, but the bottom of the <ul> gets lost outside of the browser, instead of becoming 100%-250px and vertically aligning to the middle. At least on my end...

Comment: I'm getting the same exact behavior on both, whether tall or short, in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: hmmm... well, I'll keep digging into it then see what's causing it to behave differently on mi end... thank you @Michael_B !

Comment: Is this still a problem? Could be a caching issue; Firefox is infamous for hanging on to outdated versions of stylesheets.